# How can I know which method called event handler

Tags: c#

I have two methods:

```
private void RvListen_OPT()

private void RvListen_FUT()
```

On a certain event, both call:

```
void OnRvMessageReceived(object sender, SigRvMessageEventArgs args)
```

When OnRvMessageReceived is called, how can I check which of the two methods called it? I know it can be done using the object sender, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can edit the SigRvMessageEventArgs class you could add a field to it which you set differently in the two calls.

Answer (score 1):

sender will (usually) give you the object that called the event. It may not because its up to the caller to actually set this.

That said, I"m not sure it should matter. If the call depends on who called it, maybe they need to be setup as separate events... Or, as Jackson mentioned, the args variable could be set to allow the OnRvMessageReceived event can respond to that.

Answer (score 1):

Set `sender` to a string if you can't change `SigRvMessageEventArgs` to take an additional property... But the best approach would be to modify SigRvMessageEventArgs if possible.

```
private void RvListen_OPT()
{
   OnRvMessageReceived("RvListn_OPT()", new SigRvMessageEventArgs())
}

private void RvListen_FUT()
{
   OnRvMessageReceived("RvListn_FUT()", new SigRvMessageEventArgs())
}

void OnRvMessageReceived(object sender, SigRvMessageEventArgs args)
{
   if(sender.ToString() == "RvListn_OPT()"){
      // do work
   }
   else if(sender.ToString() == "RvListn_FUT()"){
      // do work
   }
}
```